# Android UI automation test with appium

Tags: android, android-testing, appium

I just working on android UI automation test in few weeks. I tried with robotium in a time and now I want change to appium framework. And my question are:

1. I read that appium is a test tool to test webview application. So how about the other app that is not webview app?
2. Can I run test from appium on genymotion?
3. Any other tool do I need to install with appium(selenium or something)?

**Edit**
When I try to install appium with out sudo I got this error

> ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink
>   '/Users//appium/node_modules/.bin/instruments-client.js'
>
> npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink
>   '/Users//appium/node_modules/.bin/instruments-client.js']
>
> npm ERR!   errno: 3,
>
> npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>
> npm ERR!   path:
>   '/Users//appium/node_modules/.bin/instruments-client.js' }
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
>
> npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/bin/npm" "link" "appium-uiauto"
>
> npm ERR! cwd /Users/yaphatak/appium
>
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
>
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
>
> npm ERR! path
>   /Users//appium/node_modules/.bin/instruments-client.js
>
> npm ERR! code EACCES
>
> npm ERR! errno 3
>
> npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink
>   '/Users//appium/node_modules/.bin/instruments-client.js'
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users//appium/npm-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! not ok code 0

Then I try with sudo then run `appium` I got this error

> error: Appium will not work if used or installed with sudo. Please
>   rerun/install as a non-root user. If you had to install Appium using
>   `sudo npm install -g appium`, the solution is to reinstall Node using
>   a method (Homebrew, for example) that doesn't require sudo to install
>   global npm packages."

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

1- Yes, Appium can test non-webview apps.  The first line on the [Appium introduction page](http://appium.io/introduction.html?lang=en) says:

> Appium is an open-source tool you can use to automate **mobile native**, **mobile web**, and **mobile hybrid** applications on iOS and Android platforms.

2- Yes, Appium should work with Genymotion.  See [here](http://dbwest.github.io/blog/2013/09/16/appium-for-ios-and-android-automated-testing/) for an example.

3- Your tests will need to reference the [Selenium libraries](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) in order to communicate with Appium.

Comment: Thank you for clear answers. I'm installing appium so I have one more question. Edited on post.

Comment: Your edit is a completely different question.  Maybe create a new question for it?

Comment: because it is page in first place on google: try sudo `npm install -g appium@1.0.0`