# Genymotion emulator with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, genymotion

Can I integrate genymotion emulator with selenium? to do testing of Android app. functionality using selenium without device I mean using genymotion emulator.

Comment: See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199864/android-ui-automation-test-with-appium) for more details. I am inclined to say yes but I personally have never tried it.

Comment: I suggest you use robotium for automating an Android app. Genymotion also integrates nicely with it.

Comment: @Subh - Does "robotium" supports Ios mobile app testing also? OR it is for android only?

Comment: It is for android only as of now. Check the comments **Comment by jamiemul...@gmail.com, Sep 5, 2012 and  Comment by project member renasr...@gmail.com, Oct 9, 2012** in this link: [https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers).  Here, Renas(developer of Robotium) himself says it is for android, and has yet to make ways in iOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the answer and integrated successfully Genymotion with selenium.

I have done following :

1 - Install genymotion plugin in eclipse

2 - Configure Selendroid JAR file with my project

3 - Specify Genymotion device serial in my program like **capa.setSerial("192.168.xx.xxx:xxxx");**

4 - Thats it , I able to run genymotion through selenium now.